# Getting "_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist" when trying to call image_viewer module

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have a launcher application that is suppose to call functions from separate modules using a button. I have a module named "image_viewer" containing a class function that is suppose to display an image after clicking a button. The image_viewer function works fine in its original module but when I try to call it from my Launcher module I receive the error "_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist". I have included my code for the launcher and image_viewer modules for your reference below.

**image_viewer module:**

```
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image
    import tkinter as tk
    
    class ImageViewer:
        def __init__(self, root, image_filename):
            self.root = root
            self.image_filename = image_filename
    
            self.root.title('ImageViewer')
            self.root.geometry('400x350')
    
            self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root, width=300, height=300)
            self.canvas.place(x=10, y=10)
    
            self.btnView = tk.Button(text='View', command=self.view_image)
            self.btnView.place(x=20, y=265)
    
            self.btnClose = tk.Button(text='close', command=lambda:[self.destroy(), self.clear()])
            self.btnClose.place(x=65, y=265)
    
        def view_image(self):
            self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.image_filename))  # Keep ref to image.
            self.canvas.create_image(20, 20, anchor=tk.NW, image=self.img)
        def destroy(self):
            self.root.destroy()
        def clear(self):
            self.btnClose.destroy()
            self.btnView.destroy()
    
    def main(image_filename):
        root = tk.Tk()
        ImageViewer(root, image_filename)
        root.mainloop()
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main('../raw/as.png')
```

**Launcher module:**

```
    from audioplayer import audioplayer
    from texteditor import editor
    from imageviewer import image_viewer
    import tkinter as tk
    
    class Launcher:
        def __init__(self, win):  
            self.root = win
            self.root.title('Launcher')
            self.root.geometry('400x350')
            
            self.btnEditor = tk.Button(text='Editor', command=self.editor, padx=10)
            self.btnEditor.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
            self.btnEditor.place(x=5, y=315)
            
            self.btnAudio = tk.Button(text='AudioPlayer', command=self.audioplayer, padx=10)
            self.btnAudio.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
            self.btnAudio.place(x=75, y=315)
            
            self.btnImage = tk.Button(text='ImageViewer', command=self.imageviewer, padx=10)
            self.btnImage.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
            self.btnImage.place(x=178, y=315)
            
            self.quit_button = tk.Button(text = "Quit", command=self.quit, padx=10)
            self.quit_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
            self.quit_button.place(x=340, y=315)
            
        def editor(self):
            editor.main()
    
        def audioplayer(self):
            audioplayer.main()
            
        def imageviewer(self):
            image_viewer.main('../raw/as.png')
            
        def quit(self):
            self.root.destroy()
    
    def main():
        root = tk.Tk()
        Launcher(root)
        root.mainloop()
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: You shouldn't be creating two instances of `Tk`. If you need more than one window, use `Toplevel`.

Comment: Would that mean I don't need  "def main():
        root = tk.Tk()
        Launcher(root)
        root.mainloop()"  at the end of my launcher module?

Comment: You need to use `tk.Toplevel()` instead of `tk.Tk()` inside `image_viewer.main()`.